# R Cocharan's test

Tags: r, statistics

I have an excel file with 25 columns and 300 rows, every column has the same amount of rows. I need to do Cocharan's test with every column compared to every other column.

```
library(readxl)
library(outliers)

sheet2=read_excel("C:/Users/Sharas/Desktop/data.xlsx", sheet = 2)

for(i in 1:length(sheet2)) {
  for(j in i:length(sheet2)) {
     cochran.test(sheet2[[i]]~sheet2[[j]], sheet2)
  }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in split.default(X, group) : first argument must be a vector
```

typeof returns: double

```
print(typeof(sheet2[[i]])
```

Comment: You need to pass the actual formula to the `cochran.tst()` function. Something like `cochran.test( x~y, sheet2)` where `x` and `y` are column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this will get you closer:

```
# Make data.frame with possible combinations of columns.
d <- sheet2
names <- colnames(d)
name.combinations <- subset(merge(names, names), x != y)

# Run test for each combination, build formula from string.
res <- mapply(function(x, y) {
  cochran.test(as.formula(paste(x, " ~ ", y, sep = "")), d)
}, name.combinations$x, name.combinations$y)
```